# How to change storage size while restoring RDS from snapshot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, snapshot

I want to restore RDS using a snapshot.But old RDS is having 50 GB allocated storage and magnetic type allocated storage. I took snapshot of this RDS and want to restore it to general purpose SSD type. But as SSD requires 100 GB minimum. How can we restore new RDS?

Answer (score 0):

Try restoring to the same type of RDS (50GB, magnetic) and then upgrading the hardware features to the new ones (100GB, general purpose SSD).

Be aware that when you change hardware settings your RDS will go offline for a few minutes for upgrading, so your application will disconnect from the database. If it is a 24/7 app, perform this during maintanance window.

Comment: But as my databases is very big size, last time when I converted magnetic to ssd, it took 2 hours whether failover was for less time but how can we minimize this time.

Answer (score 0):

1. SSH into your old RDS instance.
2. Dump the db from your old RDS instance. Based on your db engine (be it Postgres, MySQL, or any other), there should be commands to dump your db from one instance, and restore to another.
3. Create a fresh RDS instance with the new configurations that you want.
4. Use the restore command to put the into the new RDS instance.

Refer: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/rds-db-storage-size